# Only need return flight ticket

Tags: air-travel

I can't use my outward flight ticket but need my return ticket. If I do not show on my outward flight, I am worried that the company might cancel my return flight. I have spoken to the flight company and they say I would have to cancel both tickets but the refund is so low, it's better to keep both tickets and not show for the outward flight. Should I tell the carrier that I am not going to use the outward ticket and pray they don't cancel my return flight.

Comment: The airline might indeed cancel the return flight, precisely to make it more difficult to circumvent their pricing policy.

Answer (score 0):

Each carrier has their own different rules. If your ticket specifically states "outward" and "return", then I would call the carrier to confirm the exact terms and conditions for your reservation. Generally if it is a charter flight, and you do not show for the outbound segment, then you will be treated as a "no show" and removed from the inbound sector too. If, however, your flight is scheduled/low cost, then it is more likely that you will remain on the manifest for the return (inbound) flight.